# Lostfocus on TextField?

Tags: java, frameworks, vaadin, vaadin7

I am creating a application using vaadin7, now I'm looking for how to implement lost focus on TextField but I dont have found how to.
How to implement lost focus on TextField in vaadin 7 ?

Any idea ?

thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, what is the lost focus supposed to be? Are you trying to listen to when the TextField loses focus? If so, check out addBlurListener - https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractTextField.html#addBlurListener(com.vaadin.event.FieldEvents.BlurListener)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the BlurListener.  Just create a new Listener and override the blur method.

https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/event/FieldEvents.BlurListener.html